# Ruby access multiple array elemenets by indexes (sub array)

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array and I have an array with indexes of certain elements from the first array. What is the best way to get the elements from the first array?

I am doing:

```
result = []
indexes.each { |current| result << my_array[current] }
```

But there should be a better way..

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use [Array#map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
indexes.map { |i| my_array[i] }
```

Or even better, [Array#values_at](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-values_at)

```
my_array.values_at(*indexes)
```

Where the * symbol extracts the array into arguments that get passed to the method.

Comment: I knew I was missing something 10x :)

Comment: `values_at` is the fastest, by the way. By benchmark results it is ~ 2x faster than `map` and `push`, nevertheless, it's less 'human'.